# Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing problem in my code, its telling `system.int32` cant not be converted to `system.double`, here is my code

I have an object with 4 string variables and 2 integer variables.

```
public class MyObject
{
public int id;
public string name1;
public string name2;
public string name3;
public string name4;
public int id2;

}

/*Converts DataTable To List*/
    public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this DataTable dataTable) where TSource : new()
    {
        var dataList = new List<TSource>();

        const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var objFieldNames = (from PropertyInfo aProp in typeof(TSource).GetProperties(flags)
                             select new { Name = aProp.Name, Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(aProp.PropertyType) ?? aProp.PropertyType }).ToList();
        var dataTblFieldNames = (from DataColumn aHeader in dataTable.Columns
                                 select new { Name = aHeader.ColumnName, Type = aHeader.DataType }).ToList();
        var commonFields = objFieldNames.Intersect(dataTblFieldNames).ToList();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList())
        {
            var aTSource = new TSource();
            foreach (var aField in objFieldNames)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfos = aTSource.GetType().GetProperty(aField.Name);
                propertyInfos.SetValue(aTSource, dataRow[aField.Name], null);
            }
            dataList.Add(aTSource);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

In my `objectfieldname` variable i am getting all the variable with right data type, but in `dataTblFieldNames`  variable its converting int to double, so i am facing problem in `propertyinfos` in `foreach loop` its saying

> Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.?

Any one help me to fix this please?

Comment: Where is the error? Where do you convert it?

Comment: I cannot believe you wrote Reflection/LinQ and now you are having problems with a simple Int32/double conversion. Which line?

Comment: so i am facing problem in propertyinfos.setvalue in foreach loop its saying Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx):

```
Convert.ChangeType(dataRow[aField.Name], propertyInfos.PropertyType)
```

It will try some numeric conversions (like your conversion from `double` to `int`, a change in binary representation from floating point to integer (2's complement)) and some formatting/parsing to/from `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You have find property type before assigning value and you have to also cast value to the type required because you can not directly assign double type to int type.

```
if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(int))
{
    propertyInfos.SetValue(aTSource, Convert.ToInt32(dataRow[aField.Name]), null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, its working perfect. Atlast one understood my question correctly.

Comment: but one question, why its treating it as double during set, actually the data type is int only.

Comment: @user1557020 check value coming from datatable. i think it is double.

Answer (score -1):

Your input `dataRow[aField.Name]` is of type `System.Double` while the field you want to assign to is of type `System.Int32`. But Visual Studio already told you so loud and clear.

I cannot tell you what to do because I don't know what you *want* to do. Truncate the double by casting? Round it up or down? Maybe it's the wrong field altogether? we don't know. You decide.

Considering the fact that it's pretty unlikely you came up with the above code and still did not understand the error, maybe it's a good idea to either get a full nights sleep and a good coffee or ask the one who originally wrote this code.

Comment: Hi see i have clearly said in my question what is my problem. If you cant answer please leave it. I too know vs clearly telling. My question is why its changing, in var objFieldNames  i am getting the right data type, during set(propertyInfos.SetValue(aTSource, dataRow[aField.Name], null)) how/why its changing to double, that is my question.

Comment: one of the worst reply i got it in my life :-).

Comment: Maybe you start by understanding that your first sentence in your question and your actual error message do not say the same. Your **property** is of type int, your **data** is of type double. Does not fit. You need to convert your data. And as I don't know *how* you want to do this, I can only leave this little exercise to you.